# Implement lock screen shortcut icons as there are in JellyBean android phones

Tags: android, shortcut, android-4.2-jelly-bean, unlock, screen-lock

As we see in JellyBean android phones, in the Lock screen, if we drag a Camera icon, it asks us to unlock the screen & once we unlock the screen Camera app is launched.

From my service, I am showing a dialog with OK button (& launching browser after clicking it) when the screen is locked using:

mKeyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
mKeyguardLock = mKeyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("My_App");

mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();

window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

But after clicking the OK, the browser is launched directly. What I need it after clicking the OK button, it should prompt me to unlock the screen & after I unlock, I should be taken to the browser.